# How to fix the uv mapping

Tags: uv

I have uvwrap the face with the normal unrwap option pressing u and on the projection the image is turn down side and the original image is correct. When i rotate in uv applied and render it still the same. How can i fix it. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your texture coordinates are set to Generated.
To fix your problem change mapping coordinates to **UV**

[image]

Comment: Miss one option with my mistake. Thanks for the help